# Block questions with only an url in the body

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

[Questions like this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-there-an-amphibian-mass-die-off-and-if-so-what-is-causing-it) shouldn't be possible. For heaven's sake, it's only a link **and nothing else**!

I suggest that questions with only a link in the body be blocked. I don't care what's the question; I am sure there is more to say than a copypasting a damn link. Questions like that are just insulting. (Additionally, a minimum character count wouldn't be a bad idea.)

Comment: How big of a character count do you want?  Links can contain many characters, and a legitimate question can be asked with relatively few characters.

Comment: @John: Enough to give slightly less than a two line paragraph. So around 200 characters would do it.

Comment: Isn't that solved by the downvote? Of course, I hate downvotes without an associated comment - IMO, they are just as "evil" or "unconstructive."  I don't care if it's a downvote on my question or answer (although I thankfully have very few) or someone else's.

Comment: This should really apply to _answers_ as well. They already have automatic URL detection, so if the _only_ thing in the post is a URL, it should be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would have probably put more words around it, it seems a legitimate enough question. The subject itself is already 2 questions, and the discussion item is fairly clear.

I don't think I would have missed much if this question is, in its entirety:

---

### [Block questions with only an url in the body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81765/block-questions-with-only-an-url-in-the-body)

[Questions like this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/357/is-there-an-amphibian-mass-die-off-and-if-so-what-is-causing-it)

---

For what it's worth, the next few sentences are all rant, and I'm sure by posting this question, it is clear you `don't care what's in the question`.

The last sentence does add something though.

Comment: I never said it's a bad question. In fact, it looks like an interesting topic. That's not the point. What bothers me, and should bother you, is  that he does not tell us what he knows or heard of. He just posted a link and expects an answer. "Hey guys, I heard so and so. Do the research for me please." I believe MSO calls those users "[help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)."